# Approximating function that vanishes at $0$ and $1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In $C[0,1]$, let $\mathcal A=$ Span$\{ x^n(1-x):n\ge 1\}$, Prove that $\mathcal A$ is an algebra whose uniform closure is $\{ f\in C[0,1]:f(0)=f(1)=0 \} $.

I know how to show an algebra, for the second part I tried lot but it's being hard for me to construct a polynomial that falls in $\mathcal A$ from the general polynomial which approximate given $f$. Could you please anyone help me...

Comment: Have you seen the Stone Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: I know Stone Weierstrass theorem, but $A$ vanishes at origin so i can't use that theorem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For $\epsilon > 0$, use Stone-Weierstrass to show that $A$ is dense in $C[\epsilon, 1- \epsilon]$.

(Given $0,1 \ne a \ne b$, then $a(1-a) \ne 0$ and  $a(1-a) = b(1-b) \iff a-b = a^2 -b^2 = (a-b)(a+b) \iff a = b\text{ or }a + b = 1$ And if $a+b = 1$, then use $x^2(1-x)$ - so A strongly separates $C[\epsilon, 1- \epsilon]$)

Then notice that if $g \in \{f\in C[0,1]:f(0)=f(1)=0\}$, then $g$ is a uniform limit of the functions $$g(x) = \cases{g(x) & $\epsilon < x < 1-\epsilon$ \\0 & otherwise}$$